# Creating complex JSON object and storing in Arangodb

Tags: java, arangodb

Are there any examples of creating a complex json object then storing in arangodb using the java driver? Just a bit of sample code would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the example provided in https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/java/com/arangodb/example/ExecuteDocumentQueryExample.java

It generates an AQL query and returns the result as (complex) JSON object.

Comment: It does not demonstrate how to do nested attributes and arrays however. Something similar to https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver#basic-document-operations but for these two use cases would be helpful.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Something similar: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/java/com/arangodb/example/document/AqlQueryWithSpecialReturnTypesExample.java